# JavaScript in ASP.NET validation controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can I use JavaScript like "`alter`" in validation controls in ASP.net?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant "alert" then yes you can use ValidationSummary control to show error messages in a popup. Check the links below:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wze2wh7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_validationsummary.asp)

[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_validationsum2)

Answer (score 0):

you can use custome validator and write your js code